# JSON Date format missunderstanding

Tags: java, android, json, wcf

I get the following date format JSON 
 `ExpiryDate": "/Date(-62135510400000+0000)/"`

How can i extract date from it , and make a new json in same format ???

Comment: That value represents January 4th 1AD... are you sure that's the value you want?

Comment: @PareshMayani: Well, it's a pretty common format. It's not exactly *nice*, but it's unfortunately common...

Comment: but that "/Date/" prefix, I haven't seen such JSON value yet!

Comment: @PareshMayani: See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String json = "Date(-62135510400000+0000)";
    String timeString = json.substring(json.indexOf("(") + 1, json.indexOf(")"));
    String[] timeSegments = timeString.split("\\+");
    // May have to handle negative timezones
    int timeZoneOffSet = Integer.valueOf(timeSegments[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)
    long millis = Long.valueOf(timeSegments[0]);
    Date time = new Date(millis + timeZoneOffSet);
    System.out.println(time);
```

For Date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(millis));
```

Comment: Thank you , but how can i convert a Date  into this format ??